# Searching Form Windows on C# with Data Set

Tags: c#

```
private void textBox7_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = Conn.GetConnection();
            conn.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from DATA_ITEMS where Items_Name like '" + textBox2.Text + "%'", conn);
            ds = new DataSet();
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter (cmd);
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
        }
```

I want to ask, why do you want to do a search, but when you type it in the search text box, the data in the grid view disappears (it doesn't appear).

Comment: for this kind of search, place a button and call this code  on button click. Here you open connection and never close it

Comment: Depending on the amount or data, you can load dataset and search within loaded data. Then using textChanged is not bad. And then use "refresh" button to reload the data

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing databind in the gridview

```cs
private void textBox7_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = Conn.GetConnection();
            conn.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from DATA_ITEMS where Items_Name like '" + textBox2.Text + "%'", conn);
            ds = new DataSet();
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter (cmd);
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
            dataGridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: Solved,  Change textBox2.Text to textBox7.Text